# Error trying to install GhostBSD into VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, memory, virtual-machine, freebsd

I am using Windows 10 Home on an HP laptop with an eighth-generation Intel core i5.
When I loaded GhostBSD from a live CD/DVD, when I logged in to the VM, the error was:

> The instruction at 0x00007FFB8AA50F56 referenced memory at
>   0x0000000000000008. The memory could not be read.

and the VM was aborted.

I set the allocated memory of the VM to 4096mb. The host machines RAM is a little less than 7.9GB. When I changed the allocated RAM of the VM to 2048MB, still no luck.

What's the issue? Is there any solution? I couldn't find any solution on google. I searched that quoted error and there are no results found.
Does VirtualBox not support GhostBSD? Why?

Should I do technical support instead?
Edit: the build of VirtualBox is 5.2.12-122591
Edit 2: the CPU model is i5-8250. 1.60GHz. Four cores, eight logical processors.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include which build of VirtualBox you were using

Comment: Besides the version, did you select FreeBSD in the wizard?  How far do you get in the boot process?  You may want to re-download your ISO file.  I am able to successfully install GhostBSD 11.1 in VBox 5.2.12 r122591

Comment: @essjae Yes, I selected FreeBSD 64-bit.

Comment: Oh, how far into the boot process? Up until it after I logged in it said "Performing autostart."

Comment: Actually, I got past the error. Maybe a restart of the host machine is all I need. I don't know how to explain the principle behind it.

Comment: I found out the problem. It's the audio settings for the virtual machine. It happens when I'm using Intel HD audio. It doesn't happen when I'm using SoundBlaster 16.